# Define a table length using sizeof in C

Tags: c

I want to declare a table where its size depends on another table:

```
unsigned char Tab1[] = { 10u, 11u, 12u, 15u };
unsigned char Tab2[sizeof(Tab1) / sizeof(Tab1[0])];
```

Is there any way to declare it without using the dynamic allocation?

Comment: There is no dynamic allocation there.  You could decide to use `enum { TABLE_SIZE = 6 };` and then declare `unsigned char Tab1[TABLE_SIZE]; unsigned char Tab2[TABLE_SIZE];` — they are both clearly the same size of array.

Comment: What you have written should work just fine.  `sizeof` is a compile-time operator (at least in this case).  Note that `sizeof tab[0] == sizeof (unsigned char) == 1`, so strictly speaking you don't need to do that division.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the Tab1 size is not fixed also, sorry I was not enough accurate...I updated my post!

Comment: Even with the changed definition of `Tab1`, there is no dynamic allocation.  The two `sizeof()` expressions are both compile time constants; the `Tab2` array is still the same size as `Tab1`.  `Tab1` is not a VLA; you can't provide an initializer for a VLA.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think he's using "dynamic" to mean that the compiler calculates it automatically from the initialization data, rather than having to specify it explicitly.

Comment: The simple answer is no, there's no simpler way to say "Make this array the same size as that array".

Comment: The OP needs to be aware that dynamic (memory) allocation has a meaning that is not the one you impute, @Barmar, and accuracy of terminology is kinda important.  And the answer's "No" — unless you decide that `unsigned char Tab2[sizeof((unsigned char[]){10u, 11u, 12u, 15u})/sizeof(unsigned char)];` (I can't be bothered to dererenced the zeroth element of a repeat of the compound literal) is not dynamic whereas the original code is dynamic.  The code shown in the question is about as simple as it gets, as you've said.

Comment: Dynamic allocation in C is allocating memory using one of: `malloc(); calloc(); realloc()`. your question has nothing to do with dynamic allocation

Comment: @Barmar, I meant by dynamic allocation, malloc  function.

Comment: You're not using `malloc()` in the code you posted. So what is your question? You can do it the way you posted.

Comment: @Barmar, the compiler complains about the length which is not fixed at compiling time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dynamic allocation involved in the posted definitions:

```
unsigned char Tab1[] = { 10u, 11u, 12u, 15u };
unsigned char Tab2[sizeof(Tab1) / sizeof(Tab1[0])];
```

The size of `Tab1` is not dynamic, it is determined at compile time from the initializer. There are 4 values, so `Tab1` has a size of 4 elements. The definition is equivalent to

```
unsigned char Tab1[4] = { 10u, 11u, 12u, 15u };
```

The definition of `Tab2` is fine and it will have the same number of elements as `Tab1`. Note however that there is no initializer for `Tab2`, so if this definition occurs inside the body of a function, it will be uninitialized. Accessing its contents before setting it has undefined behavior.

You mentioned in a comment that *the compiler complains about the length which is not fixed at compiling time.*  This is highly surprising: either the code posted is not the same as what you compiled or your environment is non conformant. `sizeof(Tab1) / sizeof(Tab1[0])` is a constant expression which can be used as the size for an array definition as long as the size of `Tab1` is known when the compiler parses it.

If the definition of `Tab1` is located in a different source file or after the definition of `Tab2`, and only a declaration of `Tab1` has been seen such as

```
extern unsigned char Tab1[];
```

Then the size of `Tab1` is indeed unknown and `sizeof(Tab1)` cannot be used in an expression, constant or not.